# Path generation on a graph with bidirectional weighted edges

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to do a Java implementation of a path generator on a graph with bidirectional weighted edges. The problem consists on give a route to the user based on a list of points of interest (POI) and on the user interests. The user interests, distances and travel time between all POI are already calculated. With these data I was able to create a graph with bidirectional edges where the edge's weight is the travel time between a source and a destination node.

There are some relevant user inputs:

- the time span in which he wants to travel, i.e 30 June at 4 p.m to 30 June at 8 p.m.
- the starting point (coordinates) of the trip, from where the closest POI is chosen as the trip starting point.

As the weight of the nodes is the travel time between the POI, the result path weight sum can not exceed the time span defined by the user. This will be the stoppage condition, instead of a destination node.

The user interests on a POI are defined on a range between 0 and 5. Ideally, this variable would also be considered on the path calculation, because the user would like to visit the POI with the better score.

This problem was proposed in an academic context and my knowledge in this area is not so good. If you have any suggestion of algorithm or any other idea to solve this problem in a reasonable time, I would be grateful.

Comment: Use [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) and write a [Cypher](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/) query. Neo4j has a [sandbox](https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2/)

Comment: Hi @GuyCoder, thanks for your advice. I will take a look to Neo4j, but I was trying to solve the problem in a more programmatic way,  because it needs to be demonstrated in an academic context.

Comment: And `demonstrated in an academic context` was not noted in the original question because ???. This is why I no longer write out answers for people with less than 100 rep. Don't feel bad I was in the same boat once, but if IMHO it is better to give more detail than less.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. I already changed the problem description.

Comment: Consider a different optimization: how do I travel to gain max sum of interest score within the given time.

Comment: Hi @c0der, thanks for your reply. Basically is that what I want, maximize the sum of interest score and restrict the sum of travel time to the given time. But to do that I think I must have a two weighted edge where the first weight is the time it takes to travel from one point to another and the second weight the interest score. If that's the case, I don't know how to iterate a graph with edges of two weights.

Comment: Maybe a two steps approach ? Calculate all possible paths within time limit. Store the interest score for each. At the end select the one with the highest score.

Comment: What you are describing is a variant of the Traveling Salesman Problem. I support @c0der's suggestion. You can try to build a path that goes through vertices of your graph. As you build your path, you keep track of its score and the time spent. When you reach your time limit you have a first solution. Then you can backtrack and try to find an other path that yields a higher score (sum of visited places). Note that when exploring a path if you notice that you cannot improve more than your current best answer, it is not worth trying the current path anymore. Good luck !!

Comment: @Patrick "Note that when exploring a path if you notice that you cannot improve more than your current best answer, it is not worth trying the current path anymore." can you explain ? You would know if the current pass is better than the "best path" only when you finish exploring it (meaning get to its end or the time limit).

Comment: In the original TSP you are trying to find the shortest path possible. If during a path you notice that you will exceed the length of the best path you have so far, you will stop exploring your current path and backtrack. This technique is called branch and bound. In your case it is more difficult to define an estimate of the potential gain. It is probably best if you ignore my comment for now and implement @c0der suggestion first, and later try to improve your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following procedure:

- While running search accumulate travel-time and interest-score
- Stop exploring current path if one of those conditions is met:

  - travel-time limit exceeded
  - All POIs visited
- Keep current path as best path if one of those conditions is met:

  - It is the first path explored
  - Current path has higher interest-score than best path
  - Current path has the same interest-score as best path and shorter travel-time
- Backtrack to explore another path